# How to manage the tap event on the immersive video playback view for Apple Vision Pro?

Tags: visionos, vision-pro

I'm working on a Vision Pro application that features immersive video playback.

I'd like to implement the functionality to pause/play video playback when the user taps on the immersive video playback view.

How can I handle the tap event on Vision OS?